# Configurar opciones de impresión de factura en pdf con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Existe alguna forma de poder personalizar el tamaño del papel, los márgenes y escala de un archivo a imprimir en pdf pero, directamente con JavaScript?

Es decir, estas configuraciones que dejo más abajo en un print.

Actualización - He encontrado el evento beforeprint de window pero, al imprimir por consola el evento, no encuentro algo que me pueda ayudar con ese problema en específico.

[image: Print de ejemplo de impresión]

Comment: Según tengo entendido, no puedes modificar las preferencias de impresión del usuario usando js. ¿Imaginas que cualquier página pueda modificar tus preferencias? ¡Una locura! Lo que sí puedes hacer es utilizar el media query [`@media print`](http://www.formacionwebonline.com/media-print-estilos-imprimir-desde-navegador/) para establecer los estilos con los que quieras que se imprima tu página específica. Puedes especificar hasta el [tamaño de la página](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30970423/8838721). Alternativamente puedes imprimir a pdf usando algo como [printjs](https://printjs.crabbly.com/).

Comment: no se puede acceder al menu de impresion desde js esto representaria un error de seguridad por obvias razones

Comment: Tienen razón, gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score -1):

Abri esa interfaz y presione la opcion "Inspect", alli me devolvio el HTML, creo que si podrias, al validar que cuando se abra ese ventana colocas tus datos
[image]

Comment: El problema radica en que la estructura de html no es la misma para todos los navegadores, por ende no todos utilizan las mismas etiquetas, clases, ids, etc. Pero en unos comentarios de arriba ya me respondieron, gracias